# Java program to draw two mountains

Tags: java

```
Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);
    int row = scanner.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        int column = 2 * row - 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
```

Here is my code, I managed to print out number of stars depending on user's input, but Im not sure how to print out increasing number of stars. The idea is should be know the max number of stars to be printed, then print out empty lines -> star -> empty lines. Can someone give me some ideas thanks!

Comment: hint: you'll need another for loop, one that prints spaces, before your star printing for loop. This will make an outer for loop and nested inside will be two non-nested for loops, one printing spaces followed by one printing stars. The key will be to figure out *how many* of each to print. Work it out with pencil and paper, play with the numbers, and you'll get it right!

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "draw ***two*** mountains"? Why `two`?

Comment: Its actually drawing the same 2 mountains side by side, my bad.

Comment: Then you'll need more loops. Regardless, try to work through the logic on paper. Run through the process for what happens when a user enters "2", then if he enters "3", and then "4". Do this and the logic should fall out for you.